# How to get the root element inside an applied DataTemplate when it does not have a resource key?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, xaml-resources

I wish to get the root element inside an applied `DataTemplate`. I tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements) but it does not work for me, because for the `ContentPresenter` returned by `MyItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(vm)` where `vm` is a ViewModel, `ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate` is `null`, although `ContentPresenter.Content` is the corresponding data (the same ViewModel).

I would access `DataTemplate`s as resources like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3498969/258462) but I cannot give the `DataTemplate`s resource keys because I want them to be automatically applied to all the items inside the `ItemsControl`. So I must find a way to get the `DataTemplate` from an item inside the `ItemsControl`.

I could use `if`-`else` for determining the `DataTemplate` resource in function of the `vm.GetType()` but I would like to realize what I wish without `ItemContainerGenerator` and according to the MVVM pattern, if possible, and without hard-coding types.

Below is what I think is relevant in the code. I use, for example, `MyAudioFileSelector` from `MainWindow` to load some settings from the data file into the UI and I am not sure what is the MVVM way of doing this.

## C# from my actual project

*(I suppose currently that there is only one AudioFileSelector and one ImageFileSelector, but in future probably I will have more of them.)*

```cs
internal Control GetRootControlFromContentPresenter(ContentPresenter container)
{
    // what to put here?
    return null;
}
internal AudioFileSelector MyAudioFileSelector
{
    get
    {
        foreach (SettingDataVM vm in MyItemsControl.ItemsSource)
        {
            if (vm is AudioFileSettingDataVM)
            {
                return (AudioFileSelector)GetRootControlFromContentPresenter(
                    (ContentPresenter)MyItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(vm));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
internal ImageFileSelector MyImageFileSelector
{
    get
    {
        foreach (SettingDataVM vm in MyItemsControl.ItemsSource)
        {
            if (vm is ImageFileSettingDataVM)
            {
                return (ImageFileSelector)GetRootControlFromContentPresenter(
                    (ContentPresenter)MyItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(vm));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

## Test example

### XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="wpf_test_6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_test_6"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="202" Width="274">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}">
            <TextBlock>view model 1</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel2}">
            <TextBlock>view model 2</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="MyItemsControl" Loaded="MyItemsControl_Loaded">
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### C# code-behind

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void MyItemsControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var oc = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
        oc.Add(new ViewModel1());
        oc.Add(new ViewModel2());
        MyItemsControl.ItemsSource = oc;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var container = (ContentPresenter)MyItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(oc[0]);
            // here container.ContentTemplate is null
            Debugger.Break();
        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
    }
}
public class ViewModelBase
{
}
public class ViewModel1 : ViewModelBase
{
}
public class ViewModel2 : ViewModelBase
{
}
```

Another relevant question of mine is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57971712/258462).

Thank you.

## Update 1

1. In my actual program I have more complex `DataTemplate`s. The `TextBlock` is just an example.
2. I need a `ContentTemplate` to find, for a specific container/item/index, the `DataTemplate` that was used. I use multiple `DataTemplate`s applied automatically based on their `DataType`.

## Update 2

I need `DataTemplate`s to display in a Settings window of an application different controls in an `ItemsControl`, each with the `DataContext` set to an instance of a ViewModel subtype for each setting type, e.g. `CheckBoxSettingDataVM`, `AudioFileSettingDataVM` etc. all inheriting from `SettingDataVM`.

## Update 3

I do not want to assign the `ContentTemplate` property explicitly, I want to get it so, from an item (ViewModel) I can get the container (of type `ContentPresenter`) and from it I can get the root element inside the implicit `DataTemplate` for the ViewModel, which can be `AudioFileSelector`, `ImageFileSelector` or other type. I need the `ContentTemplate` property to be different than `null` so I can store a reference to the `AudioFileSelector` and to the `ImageFileSelector` and maybe others in the future. I will use these references to load some settings from the application's opened file into these `Control`s.

Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I am still learning MVVM. I think that my problem would be solved if I could set the `DataType` of the `DataTemplate` and, even if it has a resource key, it would still be automatically applied inside the `ItemsControl`s in their scope.

## Update 4

I tried to understand better by making this scheme, I hope it helps (I realized it just complicated things, but it is part of my question.):

[image: schema]

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. Thank you very much.

Comment: The container has no reference to the `DataTemplate` that was used to create the root element. If you need a reference to this, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) problem. Why don't you explain what you want to achieve with the datatemplate or root element. Perhaps there is an easier way.

Comment: Why do you need the `DataTemplate`?

Comment: I need `DataTemplate`s to display in a Settings window of an application different controls in an `ItemsControl`, each with the `DataContext` set to an instance of a ViewModel subtype for each setting type, e.g. `CheckBoxSettingDataVM`, `AudioFileSettingDataVM` etc. all inheriting from `SettingDataVM`. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you are trying to do but implicit data templates, i.e. those without an `x:Key`, will be resolved automatically provided that they are in scope. There is no reason to assign the `ContentTemplate` property explicitly.

Comment: @mm8 I have updated my question again. Thank you.

Comment: So, we assume that you have access in your code to a viewmodel object, and you wish to retrieve the root visual element of the datatemplate that was applied to this viewmodel object when generated by the itemscontrol?

Comment: good, but this is reserved for advanced behaviours only, you should not need to retrieve this object programmatically.

Comment: @CorentinPane How can I use MVVM with settings stored in a file (for example .xml)? I posted more source code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57971712/258462). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code-behind, you can retrieve the root visual object of an instantiated `DataTemplate` by an `ItemsControl` for a given ViewModel object by doing the following:

```cs
//Assuming you have access to a viewModel variable and to your MyItemsControl:
//We retrieve the generated container
var container = MyItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(viewModel) as FrameworkElement;
//We retrieve the closest ContentPresenter in the visual tree
FrameworkElement firstContentPresenter = FindVisualSelfOrChildren<ContentPresenter>(container);
//We get the first child which is the root of the DataTemplate
FrameworkElement visualRoot = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(firstContentPresenter, 0); //this is what you want
```

You need this helper function which parses the visual tree down, looking for the first child of the correct type.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Parses the visual tree down looking for the first descendant (or self if correct type) of the given type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the descendant to find in the visual tree</typeparam>
/// <param name="child">Visual element to find descendant of</param>
/// <returns>First visual descendant of the given type or null. Can be the passed object itself if type is correct.</returns>
public static T FindVisualSelfOrChildren<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject {
    if (parent == null) {
        //we've reached the end of the tree
        return null;
    }
    if (parent is T) {
        return parent as T;
    }
    //We get the immediate children
    IEnumerable<DependencyObject> children = Enumerable.Range(0, VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)).Select(i => VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i));
    //We parse them to get the first child of correct type
    foreach (var child in children) {
        T result = FindVisualSelfOrChildren<T>(child);
        if (result != null) {
            return result as T;
        }
    }
    //Nothing found
    return null;
}
```